# How to use react-popper with render props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popper.js, react-popper

I am a beginner, trying to understand `react-popper`. On their [github](https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper), this is the example code:

```
import { Manager, Reference, Popper } from 'react-popper';

const Example = () => (
  <Manager>
    <Reference>
      {({ ref }) => (
        <button type="button" ref={ref}>
          Reference element
        </button>
      )}
    </Reference>
    <Popper placement="right">
      {({ ref, style, placement, arrowProps }) => (
        <div ref={ref} style={style} data-placement={placement}>
          Popper element
          <div ref={arrowProps.ref} style={arrowProps.style} />
        </div>
      )}
    </Popper>
  </Manager>
);
```

Is this *as it stands there* supposed to be working? I am not sure I understand how I could use this code, how it would look like if I were to import/use this `Example` Component into my own parent component; Would I need to pass `refs`? How so? It would be great if somebody could give me a working example of this code, I'd just like to see how to make use of this.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that you aim for a tooltip-like functionality. Is it what you are trying to achieve ?

Bear in mind that react-popper has a low level API. It is a positional engine rather than a tooltip library. By using it you would have to implement the logic of displaying the Popper yourself. For instance you could have a variable `shouldShowElement` and trigger changes to this

```
  ...
  <Manager>
    <Reference>
      {({ ref }) => (
        <button
          type="button"
          ref={ref}
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            /* [[SOME CODE TO SET shouldShowElement TO TRUE]] */
          }}
          onMouseLeave={() => {
            /* [[SOME CODE TO SET shouldShowElement TO FALSE]] */
          }}
        >
          Reference element
        </button>
      )}
    </Reference>
    {shouldShowElement ? (
      <Popper placement="right">
        {({ ref, style, placement, arrowProps }) => (
          <div ref={ref} style={style} data-placement={placement}>
            Popper element
            <div ref={arrowProps.ref} style={arrowProps.style} />
          </div>
        )}
      </Popper>
    ) : null}
  </Manager>
  ...
```

If you want a more high-level API you can use [react-tippy](https://github.com/tvkhoa/react-tippy)
or [react-popper-tooltip](https://github.com/mohsinulhaq/react-popper-tooltip)

Comment: @Bekinass Thank you for giving a clear understanding about the API Levels.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother too much with the render props. In most of the cases, you won't need to modify them.

Just keep in mind that

- `ref` render prop from `Reference` should be attached to the
  reference element (your item where is attached your popper).
- `ref` render prop from `Popper` should be attached on the popper
  (your tooltip or whatever).

`style` and `placement` render prop is for the geographical position on the page.

In resume, this example will render a button with an arrowed popperized `<div>` which contains `"Popper element"`.

Comment: thanks a lot again. could you give a minimal example of how this would look like in practice / in code? My level is pretty basic and I am stuck, not sure how to wire this together.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example you gave is close to be the simpliest example that may exists. The only optional "thing" is the `arrowProps` and its rendering `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks! How would I use this code though? Just like so `import Example from './Example.js'; //then in my render: <Example />` ?

Comment: No, you didn't get it. This code is not re-usable with an export. Copy its skeleton when you wanna popper something. In `Reference`, instead of the example `button`, put your reference element. In `Popper`, instead of the flying text `"Popper element"`, put the element you want to popper.